# Problems with settings file depending on configuration (debug, release)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, settings, culture

I'm now localizing my WPF application and there is this little piece of code in the constructor of the MainWindow:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Settings.Default.Language);
```

It crashes right after I start it, saying:

```
XmlParseException:{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Program.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}
its inner: CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. Parameter name: nameen-UK is an invalid culture identifier.
```

Now I know that there is no such a culture name as en-UK. I just typed it once by accident... I thought there was.

Now everything contains: en-GB. (settings, appconfig, etc.)

Steps I have done:

- restart devenv
- delete all the bin and obj folders.
- search in the entire solution for the expression: "en-UK" (with and without case sensitivity)
- search with total commander for "asterisk dot asterisk" containing the text: "en-UK" (with and without case sensitivity)

no results...

Then I put a breakpoint into the constructor and the

```
Settings.Default.Language
```

has the value "en-UK".

The point: everything works fine in release mode. It occurs only in Debug mode. How is this possible?

in release mode, the Settings.Default.Language has the en-GB value (which is fine).

Have you met this problem before? Is it a Visual Studio bug or did I go mad? Thank you.

Comment: A rule of thumb I learnt a long time ago, and which I recommend, is that if I think it's a bug in Visual Studio, it never is - it's me screwing up somewhere.

Comment: True, true. I've also experienced that many times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Visual Studio the debug mode or the release mode each one have a separated config file;
so when you debug with Debug config the old config info still registered;
try to make like this in the constructor:

```
Setting.Default.Reset();
```

if this not help you please post some code for more detail.

Comment: In the meantime I happened to solve the problem. But thank you. I don't know if your solution would have worked or not.